# Transaction Firestore Python - Weird Issue

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can't seem to figure out the issue I am having with transaction in Firestore in Python

**CODE**

```
cred = credentials.Certificate('key.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()
transaction = db.transaction()

@firestore.transactional
def addPostEvent(transaction,PID,UID,typeDef):
  ref = db.collection(u'posts').document(PID)
  snapshot = ref.get(transaction=transaction)
  transaction.update(ref, {
    typeDef: snapshot.get(typeDef) + 1
  })
  user_ref = db.collection(u'users').document(UID).collection(typeDef).document()
  user_ref.set(PID)

addPostEvent(transaction,content,uid,u'views')
```

**ERROR**

> File "/workspace/main.py", line 129, in add
> addPostEvent(transaction,content,uid,u'views') File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/transaction.py",
> line 302, in **call** result = self._pre_commit(transaction, *args,
> **kwargs) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/transaction.py",
> line 245, in _pre_commit return self.to_wrap(transaction, *args,
> **kwargs) File "/workspace/main.py", line 83, in addPostEvent user_ref.set(PID) File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/document.py",
> line 127, in set batch, kwargs = self._prep_set(document_data, merge,
> retry, timeout) File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/base_document.py",
> line 210, in _prep_set batch.set(self, document_data, merge=merge)
> File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/base_batch.py",
> line 97, in set write_pbs = _helpers.pbs_for_set_no_merge( File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py",
> line 622, in pbs_for_set_no_merge extractor =
> DocumentExtractor(document_data) File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py",
> line 422, in **init** for field_path, value in iterator: File
> "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py",
> line 359, in extract_fields for key, value in
> sorted(document_data.items()): AttributeError: 'str' object has no
> attribute 'items'